# Splash screen is not working in android app using Phonegap 3.6.3

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have create a phonegap project which platform is android and added splash screen but it is not displaying.

I've followed all the instruction for splash scrren in android from phonegap docs ( http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/config_ref_images.md.html )

and added all splash screen in all platforms/android/res/drawable* directories

My config.xml file is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.vertismirai.docconnect" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"     xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">

<name>MyApp</name>
<description>
    A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
<author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
    Apache Cordova Team
</author>
<feature name="SplashScreen">
     <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
</feature>
<icon src="res/drawable/icon.png" />
<platform name="android">
          <icon src="res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png" density="ldpi" />
          <icon src="res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png" density="mdpi" />
          <icon src="res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png" density="hdpi" />
          <icon src="res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png" density="xhdpi" />
</platform>
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />  
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova implements device-level APIs as plugins. Use the CLI's plugin command, described in The Command-Line Interface, to add this feature for a project:
Please use following link for more information

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html